# Java: change variable from outside while looping through a while queque

Tags: variables, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

I am a Java Beginner and have a little question.
I have got 2 Classes:
the first one is a java formular, the important code is:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    int key = event.getKeyCode();
    if(key == 17) {
        System.out.println("STRG");
        if(roboter.running == true) {
            roboter.running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

the second one is a class (called robot) which main part is the for loop:

```
public class Roboter {
    public boolean running = false;

    public void myFunction() {
        for(...;...;...) {
            for(...;...;...) {
                    if(!running)
                        break;
// DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT
            }
         }
     }
```

Well, this doesn't work. I think it is because I can't change the value of running while my for loop. I have no idea how to slove this problem. Maybe there is an other solution? My aim is to stop the robots myFunction if an user press a key.I hope you can help me

I am sorry for my english, if you don't undestand me I will try to rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1):

The class that handles the keyboard input should run in a separate Thread.